# How to place div at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have this rather simple setup, and would just like to move the outer div `(neumorphic-input)` to the bottom of my page. How can I do this using the current CSS I have.

I am currently using the CSS to align the two elements in the dive side by side and horizontally centred on my page.

**HTML:**

```
<body class="body">

    <div class="neumorphic-input">
        <textarea class="text-input" id="text-input" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
        <button class="send-button">Send</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.neumorphic-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;

}
```

Comment: `position:absolute; bottom:0`

Comment: you need to make the `.body { min-height: 100vh }` and then make the div absolutely ( or fixed or sticky ) positioned to `bottom: 0`

Comment: keep in mind that in order to position something absolutely, the parent needs to have `position: absolute` or `position: relative`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I tried adding ```position:absolute; bottom:0``` to the div, but it messes up the entire layout. both size and horizontal alignment

Comment: add `left: 0; right: 0` as well or `left: 0; width: 100vw`

Comment: Okay this seems to help. But why?

Comment: @Nick go ahead and read on the docs I linked in a comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `min-height: 100vh;` and some flexbox to position it at the bottom of the screen:

```css
.neumorphic-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;

}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">

    <div class="neumorphic-input">
        <textarea class="text-input" id="text-input" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
        <button class="send-button">Send</button>
    </div>

</body>
```